# how do i know how much data has been downloaded by update-manager?

Tags: update-manager, plugins

I got a pop-up from the update-manager that there are updates available for me to download and install.

I chose to install the  updates.

The process of downloading the updates has been running since a very long time; downloading the updates.

Is there a plugin for the update manager that shows how much data has it downloaded, the downloading speed etc.

I know i can calculate the difference between the size of the directory /var/cache/apt/archivers before the process begin and now, but i wish to get this on update-manager.

Currently i am getting something like the following:-

[image: without the information such as amount of data downloaded]

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you using exactly.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the **DATA** is is shown in Update Manager in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit , on the `Check` & `Install Updates` Button row as

[image]

From Update Manager image as

[image]

Or for more details try through **Terminal** doing

**`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**

Which  avails you with **DATA** info  which needs to be downloaded and the Extra space it will take after installing them as.

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  boot-repair boot-sav gir1.2-gudev-1.0 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 initscripts libgudev-1.0-0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap2-dev libnautilus-extension1a libudev0 libvlc5
  libvlccore5 nautilus nautilus-data opera python-quickly-common python-quickly-core quickly quickly-ubuntu-template resolvconf sysv-rc sysvinit-utils udev vlc-data
24 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 31.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 929 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

To see the **progress** of data being downloaded , press`y` to continue updating through Terminal , you will get as

[image]

Comment: but i want to get the current progress of the data being downloaded and the downloading speed.

Comment: Look into using `apt-fast`. Some links are [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=818619). That should give you the information you want.

Comment: i think i am miss understood; what i want is that "i want to get the progess(verbose), like how much data has been downloaded till now and what is the current downloading speed with which update manager is downloading the updates".

Comment: @Ankit - Yes , i understood what you said , but did you tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` , it shows the download speed and the data (current package) being dowwnloaded.